# Please prove that if a ring has a finite number of elements, then the characteristic of $R$ is a positive integer.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

My proof is:

Let $R$ have $n$ elements

Let $x \in R$

If $G$ is a finite group and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ then order of $
G = (\text{order of $H$})(\text{index of $H$ in $G$})$. Therefore, we get $o(x) \mid n$.

Thus, $nx=0$
Therefore, for there does not exist a positive $n$ such that $nx=0$ for all $x \in R$.
Hence the characteristic of $R$ is a positive integer.

I was wondering how I could rewrite this to improve the proof or what could be changed to help show my point. Thank you

Comment: What is your definition of "characteristic of a ring"? And are your rings required to have an identity, or not?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to MSE!

You have the right idea, but you should probably be a bit more clear. Notably, you know that $R$ the *ring* is also an (abelian) *group* under $+$.

So then, as you've noted, the order of every element in the group $(R,+,0)$, has to divide $|R|$. In particular, it's finite.

This is the second place you need to be clearer: The characteristic is the additive order of $1$. So since we know that *every* element has finite additive order, then in particular $1$ does. Then we have $\text{Char}(R) = o(1) \mid n$, so $\text{Char}(R) < \infty$, as desired.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Is there a different way to write (order of H)(index of H in G)

Comment: Why not $|H|$ and $[G:H]$ respectively?